# How do I pivot MySQL INNER JOIN results in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have the following 2 MySQL tables:

players:

```
| id | name    |
|----|---------|
| 1  | Player1 |
| 2  | Player2 |
| 3  | Player3 |
```

scores:

```
| key | id | round | score |
|-----|----|-------|-------|
| 1   | 1  | Rd1   | 20    |
| 2   | 1  | Rd2   | 22    |
| 3   | 1  | Rd3   | 19    |
| 4   | 2  | Rd1   | 18    |
| 5   | 2  | Rd2   | 23    |
| 6   | 2  | Rd3   | 19    |
```

where scores.id=players.id

I will have upwards of 90 players in my 'players' table, what's the best way to query this and insert it into an HTML table to make it easier to view? I'm hoping to have an output similar to this:

```
| Player  | Round 1 | Round 2 | Round 3 |
|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| Player1 | 20      | 22      | 19      |
| Player2 | 18      | 23      | 19      |
```

This is my first attempt at normalizing data in tables. Am I going to have to do  number of cases? I'm not sure what the best way to pivot the data is with an INNER JOIN.

Comment: so what did you try to do so far?

Comment: `"select t1.ID,
t1.name,
t2.round,
from players as t1
INNER JOIN scores as t2
on t1.id=t2.id
ORDER BY id asc
");` I haven't been able to figure out how to bring in the round in separate columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution, hope it helps :

```
SELECT
    name as Player,  
    SUM(CASE WHEN (s.round='Rd1') THEN s.score ELSE 0 END) AS Round1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (s.round='Rd2') THEN s.score ELSE 0 END) AS Round2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (s.round='Rd3') THEN s.score ELSE 0 END) AS Round3

FROM 
    players p
    JOIN scores s
    on s.id=p.id
GROUP BY 
    name
```

This will output :

```
| Player  |  Round1 |  Round2 |  Round3 |
|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| Player1 | 20      | 22      | 19      |
| Player2 | 18      | 23      | 19      |
```

This [**Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/74TE8983194iehd9d2ma7i/0) for you to test!

Answer (score 1):

I have a sligthly alternative solution which uses subqueries with the following benefit that players with no no score gets listed too!!

```
    SELECT
     p.name,  
    ifnull((select score from scores where id = p.id and round='Rd1' limit 1), 0) as Round1,
    ifnull((select score from scores where id = p.id and round='Rd2' limit 1), 0) as Round2,
    ifnull((select score from scores where id = p.id and round='Rd3' limit 1), 0) as Round3
FROM  players p        
GROUP BY p.name, p.id
```

Comment: I'll try this as well based on the data in my tables. Thanks!

Comment: I think you maybe could use - https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php - which is a nice feature of mysql.